# AngularJS: Prevent page refresh when transitioning between routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I had a problem previously where I wanted to prevent the page from refreshing when programmatically updating the URL.

I have a "home" view, e.g: /books and I have specific views: e.g: /books/123

The home page has a couple of side panels and a main panel with the list of books.
When clicking on a book, I only want the main panel to update, leaving the rest of the page as it is, but I DO want to update the URL to reflect the book that is loaded. All books should be directly linkable, and so the URL reflects this direct link. I update the URL by setting $location.path() when a specific book is loaded, and I use reloadOnSearch:false in my ui-router state to prevent the refresh.

My routes are set up as follows:

```
.state('books', {
   url: '/books',
   title: 'Books',
   templateUrl: CONFIG.static_url + '/html/book.html',
   controller: 'BookCtrl'
})
.state('book', {
   url: '/books/:itemId',
   title: 'Books',
   templateUrl: CONFIG.static_url + '/html/book.html',
   controller: 'BookCtrl',
   reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

This works fine, but it has two problems.

1) When transitioning from the home "Books" page, to a specific book, the page IS refreshed. When transitioning from one specific book to another, the model updates without refreshing the page (which is the desired behaviour).

2) When using the browser back/forward controls, the change in URL is not reflected in the model and so the view doesn't update. However, it does work when transitioning to/from the home page to a specific page.

To fix problem 2, I have set a $watch on $location.path() so if it changes and it doesn't match with the model, I load in the correct item. This appears to work fine.

However, problem 1 remains. How can I seamlessly transition from the Home page, to a specific view, without the whole page refreshing while also retaining the browser back/forward functionality? I can probably continue to use the $watch functionality to update based on the URL, but I can't seem to get it to load without the page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make `book` a child of `books` and change its URL just to `/:itemId`.
2. Do not manually set `$location.path()`, as this will force a refresh. Redirect between states using `ui-sref` directive or `$state.go()` function.

Try something like this:

```
.state('books', {
    url: '/books',
    // ... (template should contain <div ui-view></div> where sub-state content will be rendered)
})
.state('books.book', {
    url: '/:itemId',
    // ... (template and controller just for this sub-state; will get rendered into super-state's ui-view)
})
```

and link like this:

```
<a ui-sref="books.book({itemId:123})">Book 123</a>
```

Comment: This looks promising.. I've just switched over to using ui-router and so I'm still trying to get my head round how it works. With my routes set up as they are, I need to be able to play out a partial template if on the "books" homepage, so when going to /books it would play out the main books template AND the "list of books" partial nested template. At the moment, I've got round this by adding another sub-state: /books/home (books.home). Is there some way I can include the sub-state by default, but switch it out when viewing a specific item?

Comment: You can define separate views in the super-state with their default content and then change them from sub-states. See the [developer guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). However, creating a sibling state is perfectly fine and tests much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the book as a child state of the books. By using that you achieve the required behavior as the book html will already be available for the route. I hope that will work.